# How can I redirect to the previous page after google login in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, google-signin, angular-social-login

How can I redirect to the previous page after google login in Angular8?

I am saving the current URL in the localStorage and I am using it to navigate back when the user successfully login. But it is not navigating.

This is my AuthService with login function.

```
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth , private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  login() {
    let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || '/';
    localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', returnUrl);
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

}
```

This is my AuthGuardService

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, public router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.auth.user$.pipe(map(user => {
      if (user) { return false; }

      this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams : {returnUrl : state.url}});
      return true;
    }));
  }
}
```

I am using app.component.ts to navigate to the previous page.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, router: Router) {

    auth.user$.subscribe(user => {
      if(user){
        let returnUrl = localStorage.getItem('returnUrl');
        router.navigate([returnUrl]);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

This is my app.module.ts where I have defined the routes.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
      { path: "check-out", component: CheckOutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]  },

       //...

    ])
```

I am trying to access 'check-out' page from the address bar. Then it's redirecting to the login page as I want.
(When the user is not login and when the user tries to access to 'check-out' page it is directing to the login page.)
My URL looks like this with router parameters.

```
http://localhost:4200/login?returnUrl=%2Fcheck-out
```

But after the login, it's not redirecting back to the 'check-out' page.

After login of a user, my URI looks like this

```
http://localhost:4200/login?returnUrl=%2Fcheck-out
```

It hasn't changed. But in app.component.ts  I am trying to navigate.

I can't find why this is not navigating back to the 'check-out' page after the successful login of a user.

Comment: Why don't you open up a pop-up ? That would resolve your routing issue by not changing your URL at all.

Comment: Popup for the google login?

Comment: Yes, from what I remember, Firebase works like that, it opens up a pop-up (a second browser window) to ask you for your credentials.

Comment: In some cases you can't use popup, such as right now when trying to do this at this particular moment with firebase / angularfire and SSR. Also it's a better user experience in my opinion to not have a popup

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution after struggling with this for a full day.

Create a service for all the url operations:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PreviousRouteService {

  public setPreviousUrl(url: string) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('previousUrl', url);
  }

  public getPreviousUrl() {
    const previousUrl = sessionStorage.getItem('previousUrl');
    return previousUrl;
  }

  public deletePreviousUrlKey() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('previousUrl');
  }
}
```

Back in your guard, if they were not logged in, use state.url to get the url they were trying to go to and save it:

```
// save the route
this.previousRouteService.setPreviousUrl(state.url);
```

Use signInWithRedirect as you did before:

```
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
```

Note that in AF 6 that extra .auth is dropped, so would look like:

```
this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
```

After the signInWithRedirect is completed, you will be sent back to where you came from. I can't quite tell from your code, but I'm assuming that is the login page. So on that login page in the constructor put (again note I've dropped the extra .auth here for AF 6):

```
this.userSub = this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
    this.loggedIn = !!user;
    this.user = user;
    const previousRoute = this.previousRouteService.getPreviousUrl();
    if (previousRoute) {
      this.router.navigate([previousRoute]).then(() => {
        // now reset so don't keep going back if coming to login page
        // put some time otherwise it will delete it before above is finished
        //   even though that shouldn't be the case...
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.previousRouteService.deletePreviousUrlKey();
        }, 8500);
      });
    }
  });
```

This isn't the most elegant solution I'm sure, but it works. I don't really know why the setTimeout is necessary either after the previous route is navigated to - what's the point of having a promise if it hasn't finished yet? Or maybe it's to do with how the authState is working and emitting, don't know but maybe a better engineer can explain. Anyways, there ya go.